# What replaces "~/.gnome2/terminal.ini"?

Tags: files, gnome-terminal

A long time ago, I would use the save command from the Gnome terminal to save my changes to the `"terminal.ini"` file. After a while, that was broken and it would mess up my settings, so I started using `vim` to edit the file directly.

However, it looks like that file is ignored in 16.04. It was probably copied somewhere else and the new file used.

Any idea where the new file is and what it is named?

---

From the comment, I thought that maybe I had some info about that on one of my Linux pages and indeed, here it is:

http://linux.m2osw.com/autohide-gnome-panel-when-two-panels-are-bottom

I see that we had a `gnome-session-save` before, but that command is gone now. The way I reference the `terminal.ini` files is through a Desktop file that looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --load-config=/home/alexis/.gnome2/terminal.ini
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=Gnome Terminal
Name=Gnome Terminal
Comment[en_US]=Load terminal using ~/.gnome2/terminal.ini
Comment=Load your Gnome terminal from ~/.gnome2/terminal.ini file
```

I have this Desktop file in my autostart directory:

```
/home/<user-name>/.config/autostart/gnome-terminal.desktop
```

So I guess the name did not change, yet I changed a path and somehow it still opens with the old path...

Okay, I found it! Sorry for the noise... I now have a `terminals.desktop` file which runs a new script:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/home/alexis/bin/terminals
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=Terminals
Name=Terminals
Comment[en_US]=Gnome Terminals
Comment=Gnome Terminals
```

And that script is as follow:

```
gnome-terminal \
    --geometry=147x24--10-14 \
    --tab --working-directory "/home/<user>/<path1>" \
    --tab --working-directory "/home/<user>/<path2>" \
    --tab --working-directory "/home/<user>/<path3>" \
    --tab --working-directory "/home/<user>/<path4>" \
    --tab --working-directory "/home/<user>/<path5>" \
    --tab --working-directory "/home/<user>/<path6>"
```

So indeed, the old terminal.ini is ignored and the problem most certainly started happening in 14.04 and not 16.04.

Comment: By default, terminal history is saved in ~/.bash_history , try running some commands, close the used terminal and check the mentioned file.

Comment: The `terminal.ini` file is to describe the terminal(s) when I start X11. (if you log out and log back in, then `terminal.ini` was read to open the xterm window with, in my case, 6 terminals each `cd`-ed in specific folders.)

Comment: @M.Becerra, okay, I actually found the problem. It probably changed in 14.04 and I completely forgot about the fact that `terminal.ini` was not used anymore. Instead I run a script that specifies the working directory of each tab "manually".